# Mini batch-training of a scikit-learn classifier where I provide the mini batches

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata

I have a very big dataset that can not be loaded in memory.

I want to use this dataset as training set of a scikit-learn classifier - for example a `LogisticRegression`.

Is there the possibility to perform a mini batch-training of a scikit-learn classifier where I provide the mini batches?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that some of the classifiers in `sklearn` have a [`partial_fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) method. This method allows you to pass minibatches of data to the classifier, such that a gradient descent step is performed for each minibatch. You would simply load a minibatch from disk, pass it to `partial_fit`, release the minibatch from memory, and repeat.

If you are particularly interested in doing this for Logistic Regression, then you'll want to use [`SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier), which can be set to use logistic regression when `loss = 'log'`.

You simply pass the features and labels for your minibatch to `partial_fit` in the same way that you would use `fit`:

`clf.partial_fit(X_minibatch, y_minibatch)`

**Update**:

I recently came across the [`dask-ml` library](http://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/incremental.html#scikit-learn-s-partial-fit) which would make this task very easy by combining `dask` arrays with `partial_fit`. There is an example on the linked webpage.

Comment: You can also partially fit a `LogisticRegression` instance

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the scaling strategies included in the  `sklearn` documentation:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html

A good example is provided here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html