# Combine Coefficients of Regression from multiple training sets in scikit Linear Regression

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a million rows in my training data set, of i am performing the fit in batches. Is there any way to combine the coefficients generated from different batches.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may use `SGDClassifier` or `SGDRegressor` with their [`partial_fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) method.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/are-there-algorithms-for-computing-running-linear-or-logistic-regression-param

Comment: Also see: [Mini batch-training of a scikit-learn classifier where I provide the mini batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927095/mini-batch-training-of-a-scikit-learn-classifier-where-i-provide-the-mini-batche)